# I have two dataframes of unequal lengths I want to combine with specific NA placement

Tags: r

Sorry about the bad title. It's the best I could come up with.

I have two dataframes I want to combine (df1 and df2). df1 is a different length than df2. I do not want information about df1 on the same row as df2. I want to fill the rest of the empty spaces with NA.

If possible, I prefer a tidyverse solution.

df1 and df2:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Alpha = c(2,2),
                  Bravo = c(3,3))

df2 <- data.frame(Charlie = c(1,1,1),
                  Delta = c(2,2,2))
```

This is want I want:

```
df3 <- data.frame(Alpha = c(2,2,NA,NA,NA),
                  Bravo = c(3,3,NA,NA,NA),
                  Charlie = c(NA, NA, 1,1,1),
                  Delta = c(NA, NA, 2,2,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
bind_rows(df1, df2)

  Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta
1     2     3      NA    NA
2     2     3      NA    NA
3    NA    NA       1     2
4    NA    NA       1     2
5    NA    NA       1     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a `tidyverse` solution but a base R one.

One way would be to reconstruct the new dataframe based on the input dataframe.

```
final <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(df1) + nrow(df2), 
   ncol = ncol(df1) + ncol(df2), dimnames = list(NULL, c(names(df1), names(df2)))))

final[1:nrow(df1), names(df1)] <- df1
final[(nrow(df1) + 1):nrow(final), names(df2)] <- df2

final
#  Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta
#1     2     3      NA    NA
#2     2     3      NA    NA
#3    NA    NA       1     2
#4    NA    NA       1     2
#5    NA    NA       1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2))
```